# How is Main(...) called in referenced project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-client-side

I'm learning Blazor and using this well known example:

https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/FlightFinder

The FlightFinder.Server project gets started and somewhere the referenced FlightFinder.Client project has the Main method called in its program.cs which builds/runs another host.

I can't figure out where this happens and I've been trawling through the documentation and Google for hours. As far as I can see there is no direct reference to that method in the FlightFinder.Server project.

Either I'm missing something or maybe this is such common knowledge nobody has written it down anywhere. I thought it might have something to do with UseClientSideBlazorFiles or MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor but I can't see how it works.

Please help me not go insane and understand.

Comment: Why do you want to call the Main method which is in Client project in Server project?

Comment: This isn't something I'm trying to accomplish, it's something that is happening in the example code and I can't understand why. When "dotnet run" gets used in the FlightFinder.Server directory the Main method in FlightFinder.Server/Program.cs gets called and a host gets set up. At some later point the Main method in the FlightFinder.Client/Program.cs file gets called and I cannot see where it happens. It's definitely getting called because removing the **CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();** line in FlightFinder.Client/Program.cs breaks the app.